# Why are the px.bar colors getting brighter/lighter when size of the data getting bigger?

Tags: pandas, plotly, bar-chart, histogram, plotly-python

I have a problem with plotly bar when using with 2 categorical columns , the graph is working but not clear as you can see .
I changed colors but still the same .

Data sample :

```
Job                y

Housemaid          yes 
Admin.             No
Services           yes
Services           no
```

A very simple code but couldn't figure out the problem .

```
fig = px.bar(bank_data ,x="job", color="y")
fig.show()
```

here is what I get

[plotly bar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNHLg.png)

edit:
it depends on the size of the data , for example when  I use  1000 row ,that's what I get .

[image]

but when I use 2000 row , the color become lighter
[image]

that's why it isn't clear at all when using all of the data.

used data : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/volodymyrgavrysh/bank-marketing-campaigns-dataset

**Edit:** solved by adding another column "count", then groupby "job" :

```
bank_data["count"]=1
bank_data=bank_data.groupby(["job","y"],as_index=False).sum()
fig=px.bar(bank_data,x="job",y="count",color="y",barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

The result is that:
[image]

Comment: Please check out the dataset and try to add some dummy data to your question.

Comment: Added sample of the data . Actually the graph isn't empty, but it isn't clear for some reason .

Comment: Does this link solve your problem? https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-visualize-3-columns-with-boolean-values/36181/2

Comment: This is another way to get the same result , but i am trying to figure the problem with this code . I think the problem is somehow related to the size of the dataset as it worked fine with part of the data.

Comment: You could get a correct plot with boolean variables?

Comment: The problem is in the type of columns because they are boolean.

Comment: @Hamzah   It works fine with boolean variables , the problem is with the strength of the color , it becomes unclear when the size of the data becomes bigger .

Comment: It is special case in your data. Could you share some of the data especially from the size when the color problem arises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is to count number of yes and no for each job, therefore you can use px.histogram with `barmode='group'`for this task rather than creating new column in your dataframe as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('bank-additional-full.csv',sep=';')

fig = px.histogram(df ,x="job", color="y",barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Your problem is mentioned [here](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want,bar%20charts) and it is proposed to use hisogram rather than the bar.